# What's the correct way to link to the same page multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to have a single page that can show the same type of data (lets say fruits). Then I want to load this page anywhere in my website hierarchy but each time with different parameters.

I have my main page like the following with two links to the same page `show.html`:

```html
<div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top" data-theme="a" class="nav-ecommera">
    <ul >
      <li>
        <a href="show.html?p=apples" data-role="button">Apples</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="show.html?p=oranges" data-role="button">Oranges</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

A click on each of the two buttons will create a new instance of the page `show.html` in the DOM. All of the items in show.html therefore will have duplicate ID's in the DOM.

In my javascript I want to dynamically fill the show.html page:

```js
$('div[id="show"]').live("pagebeforeshow", function(e, data) {
     var p = getUrlParameter("p");
     show(p);
});

var show = function(p) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://show.com/?p='+p,
        success: function(data) {
                    // Refresh 'show' page with new data
                    // First time: It's fine.
                    // Second time: 'show' page is duplicated in the DOM so it's messy.
                 } 
    });
}
```

Now the first time `show.html` loads everything is fine. However the second time everything in `show.html` is loaded twice and the DOM includes many duplicate ID's.

Is there a way to remove the first page from DOM before loading the new one?

Or:

Is there a better approach that will do what I'm trying to achieve here?

**UPDATE:**
I already tried removing previous instances of `show` pages when loading a new one. It works as far as showing the second page is concerned. But there is a problem when the first page needs to be shown for the second time, after being manually removed.

I think the reason is jQuery mobile seems to think the first page is already loaded, despite the fact that we manually removed it. So it doesn't fully reload the first page when accessed again. I'm talking about this sequence of navigation: Home -> Apples -> Back to home -> Oranges -> Back to home -> Apples (Here you get a defected page).

Answer (score 1):

1) You could change ID`s to classes.

2) You can have wrapper that encloses the show.html and when you try to load it second time find the one you loaded previous and delete it.

Your show.html:

```
<div class='previous-load'>
  ... enclosed show.html HTML ...
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('div[id="show"]').live("pagebeforeshow", function(e, data) {
     var p = getUrlParameter("p");
       show(p);
});

var show = function(p) {

    $(".previous-load").remove();

    $.ajax({
        url:'http://show.com/?p='+p,
        success: function(data) {
                    // Refresh 'show' page with new data
                    // First time: It's fine.
                    // Second time: 'show' page is duplicated in the DOM so it's messy.
                 } 
    });
}
```

Comment: I already tried removing previous pages. It works fine as it will correctly show the second page. But the problem appears when the first page wants to be relaoded. For some reason jquery mobile thinks the first page must be already loaded, so it doesn't fully reload the first page. (I'm talking about this sequence of navigation: Home -> Apples -> Back to home -> Oranges -> Back to home -> Apples (Here you get a defected page).

Answer (score 1):

You can load the `show.php` page via `$.mobile.changePage()` which has the `reloadPage` option:

```
//bind to all links that have an HREF attribute that starts with "show.html"
$('a[href^="show.html"]').bind('click', function () {

    //set a default query-string for the page-load
    var query = '';

    //if this link's HREF attribute has a query-string, use it
    if (this.href.indexOf('?') > -1) {
        query = this.href.split('?')[1];
    }

    //forward the user to the page, telling jQuery Mobile to reload the page
    //which will use the new query-string sent
    $.mobile.changePage('show.html', { reloadPage : true, data : query });

    //prevent the default behavior of the click
    return false;
});
```

> **reloadPage** (*boolean*, default: false)
>
> Forces a reload of a page, even if it is already in the DOM of the
>   page container. Used only when the 'to' argument of changePage() is a
>   URL. Here is the documentation for `$.mobile.changePage()`:

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html*

When jQuery Mobile loads the same page twice it's because the URL in the HREF attribute does not match the `data-url` attribute on the pseudo-page elements. For debugging this issue, make sure to check what `data-url` attribute is being added to your `show.html` page as it's inserted in to the DOM. If it doesn't seem to match-up, then you can set a `data-url` attribute on the element like:

```
<div data-url="/show.html" data-role="page" id="show-page">
    ...
</div>
```

Then you would always link to the page using the URL: `/show.html`

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work either. Home -> Oranges -> Back to home -> Oranges will show a defected page.